# Testing interactions with non-normal ordinal data

Tags: anova, data-transformation, ordinal-data, small-sample, measurement-error

I am testing a hypothesis in which my **scale DV (PSS)** is predicted by an interaction between an Ordinal DV and a scale IV.

The **ordinal IV** is **TF** (Total Freq)

The **scale IV** is and **PQM** (Practice Quality).

**TF** is the sum of two ordinal variables:**FF**(Formal Freq) and **IF**(Informal Freq)

Each is measured as follows:

A) never/almost never, B) 1/week, C) 2-3/week, D)Almost Everyday, E) Everyday, F) Two or more times/day, More than three times/day]

**PQM** Is a validated scale made up of the means of two sub scales comprising 3 questions which are each being measured from 0% to 100%.

My hypothesis is that high scores on **TF** (a composite of **FF** and **IF**) predict lower **PSS (DV)** scores only when **PQM** is also high.

Given that **FF** and **IF** are measuring frequency using unequal intervals(i.e. jump from 2 times a week to 'almost everyday'), what are my options for testing my hypothesis?

In terms of combining them: I figured I would centre each variable by subtracting the mean from each score and then add **FF(centred)** and **IF(centred)** to get **TF**

I currently think I have these options:

1) Do the regression assuming my ordinal DV's are scale

2) Dummy code my ordinal DVs and do the regression (Low vs High; coding them 0 and 1)

3) Do a one way ANOVA after reducing all variables to categories of Low/High

4) Do LOGARITHMIC TRANSFORMATIONS on ordinal variables and reduce scale variables to Low/High

In any of these cases I am not sure if I should enter **TF** alone or instead enter **FF** and **IF** together. I am also wondering the same thing about **PQM** which is made up of two opposing subclass (positive measure and negative measure).

The rationale for entering **FF** and **IF** separately is that the literature shows that only one predicts my **DV** and not the other.

I have a small sample of only about N=34. If list-wise deletion is used the total N is only around 25. 
**

- Tl;Dr

**

I have two ordinal IVs (unequal intervals within each) , one scale IV and a scale DV and am wondering a) what test to use to test for an interaction between my DVs b) what transformations I need to perform and c) how to best calculate and enter composite measures into the statistical test.

Thank you if you got this far! I look forward to hearing your responses.